# How do I add diff markers to the fringe in emacs?

Tags: version-control, emacs

I'm using GNU Emacs 23, but answers for other emacsen are welcome as a jumping-off point.

For files under version control I'd like to have diff markers show up in the fringe, something like the markers that subclipse uses:

[image]
<sub>(source: [tigris.org](http://subclipse.tigris.org/images/workspace-ss.png))</sub>

It seems like this would be possible by parsing the output of `vc-diff` and using the built-in support for the fringe, but I don't want to reinvent this particular wheel unless I really have to.

Answer (score 3):

Not quite the same, but you could diff the file and then use [MiniMap](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/MiniMap).

Comment: An approach like minimap is probably the most realistic.  AFAIK the fringe is row-based: although it can display graphics they cannot be scaled to arbitrary proportions.  Using a separate buffer like minimap however would work and could offer some interesting additional capabilities.  A feature like that would sure be nice!

Comment: sounds promising, but can you elaborate?